# Executing mail -s "testing" myemail@gmail.com just hangs. Why?

Tags: centos, sendmail, postfix-mta

I'm debugging a problem with a script not emailing out.

When i execute the following outside of the script:

```
mail -s "testing" myemail@gmail.com
```

It just hangs. The terminal doesn't give me any feedback what it's doing or if it has finished. I can only enter a another command by `CTRL + C`ing it. Any ideas why? Sometimes it does work if I let it hang long enough (I will get an email about 2 - 4 minutes later).

I'm running CENTOS 5 something. I've just uninstalled sendmail and installed postfix to see if this fixes it and the same thing appears to be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter the above and hit  it should take you to a blank line and wait for you to type the actual text of the message.  Once you've completed entering the message, you enter a `.<enter>` (dot or period followed by enter key) as the first character on a line and (depending on the version), it will usually ask you to enter any CC: addresses.  Hit  again to proceed past that and it should then send the mail.

The above command doesn't actually send anything, the `-s` sets the subject, but unless you include a file it will simply wait for you to type something.  If, on the other hand, you want it to just send something quickly you can have it pull in a file as the content of the message, e.g. `mail -s "testing" myemail@gmail.com < some_text_file`.  This will read `some_text_file` into the body of the email and send it immediately.